# JSON Array handling inside JSON_OBJECT in mariaDB

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I am new to mariadb 10.2 and trying to create a json object using below query

```
SELECT 'VisaType', JSON_OBJECT('VisaTypes', CONCAT('[',(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('VisaTypeId', a.visatypeid, 
                                'Name', a.resourcevalue))),']'))
        FROM cte a
```

The result i am getting is

```
{"VisaTypes": "[{\"VisaTypeId\": \"40eb54e3-22db-e711-8228-0a1a4261e962\", \"Name\": \"Maritime/Aviation Crew\"},{\"VisaTypeId\": \"c2eb54e3-22db-e711-8229-0a1a4261e962\", \"Name\": \"Maritime/Aviation Crew\"},{\"VisaTypeId\": \"886d8088-ff30-e811-92cd-0a1a4261e962\", \"Name\": \"Visa Vietnam\"}]"}
```

which is invalid as per JSON_VALID.
But when I remove double quotes of the value ("[ --> [) , it shows a valid JSON.

```
{"VisaTypes": [{\"VisaTypeId\": \"40eb54e3-22db-e711-8228-0a1a4261e962\", \"Name\": \"Maritime/Aviation Crew\"},{\"VisaTypeId\": \"c2eb54e3-22db-e711-8229-0a1a4261e962\", \"Name\": \"Maritime/Aviation Crew\"},{\"VisaTypeId\": \"886d8088-ff30-e811-92cd-0a1a4261e962\", \"Name\": \"Visa Vietnam\"}]}
```

How can I get a valid JSON directly from my query? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `CONCAT` generated a string; you wanted an array.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8bc2f76284c1f22f87361b284e232e4b), however, I would recommend using [JSON_ARRAY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_array/).

Comment: ```SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT('[',(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('VisaTypeId', a.visatypeid, 
                                'Name', a.resourcevalue))),']'), '"[', '['), ']"', ']'), '\\"', '"') AS a
        FROM cte a``` 
Just replace \"